# Get all positions of elements in STL vector that are greater than a value

Tags: stl, vector, std, c++

I would like to know how can I find the index positions of elements that verify a certain condition (for example greater than). For example if I have a vector of int values

```
vector<int> V;
```

V contains the values `3 2 5 8 2 1 10 4 7`

and I want to get all the **index positions** of elements that are greater than 5.
I know `std::find_if` but according to the documentation it just finds the first element that satisfies a condition.

Comment: You can use `std::find_if` in a loop, storing positions as you go.

Comment: use it repeatedly, starting not from the beginning but from where you just found.

Comment: @oldrinb Actually I need to get the positions because then I have to get elements from another vector at the same positions.

Comment: @tuxworker, So you want index positions, not iterators?

Comment: @chris yes I want index positions

Comment: @tuxworker it sounds like you really should be using an `std::map`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Loop `std::find_if`, starting from where you stopped last time.

Sample ([see it work](http://liveworkspace.org/code/cab9da03219819a00c4dc97bfe49c4d6)):

```
std::vector<size_t> results;

auto it = std::find_if(std::begin(v), std::end(v), [](int i){return i > 5;});
while (it != std::end(v)) {
   results.emplace_back(std::distance(std::begin(v), it));
   it = std::find_if(std::next(it), std::end(v), [](int i){return i > 5;});
}
```

First we set up the iterator with the first result. If it's not found, the while loop never executes. Otherwise, the index position is stored (`std::distance` is basically a more generic `it - std::begin(v)`), and the search continues onward.

Answer (score 10):

I think I'd use `std::copy_if`:

```
std::vector<int> x{3, 2, 5, 8, 2, 1, 10, 4, 7};
std::vector<size_t> y(x.size());

std::iota(y.begin(), y.end(), 0);
std::copy_if(y.begin(), y.end(), 
             std::ostream_iterator<size_t>(std::cout, " "), 
             [&](size_t i) { return x[i] > 5; });
```

For me, this gives `3 6 8`, the indices of 8, 10 and 7 in `x` -- exactly what we want.

If you're stuck with a C++98/03 compiler/library, you'll use `std::remove_copy_if` instead (and reverse the sense of the comparison). In this case, you obviously won't be able to use a lambda for the comparison either.

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, `transform_if` algorithm:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template<typename InputIterator, typename OutputIterator,
    typename UnaryPredicate, typename UnaryFunction>
OutputIterator
transform_if (InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
    OutputIterator result, UnaryPredicate pred,
    UnaryFunction func)
{
    for (; first != last; ++first, ++result)
        if (pred(*first))
            *result = func(*first);
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> x {3, 2, 5, 8, 2, 1, 10, 4, 7};
    std::vector<size_t> indices;

    size_t index = 0;
    transform_if(x.begin(), x.end(), std::back_inserter(indices),
        [&](int i){ return ++index, i > 5; },
        [&](int){ return index-1; });

    std::copy(indices.begin(), indices.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<size_t>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Output: `3 6 8`

Comment: Notice that some predicates in std have requirements which would forbid `index` modification inside the predicate (as unspecified call order (to allow parallelism for example)). Fortunately, `transform_if` is your version, so you have control over it.

Answer (score 0):

In C++20, with view, you might do

```
std::ranges::iota_view{0, (int)v.size()}
    | std::ranges::views::filter([&v](int i){ return v[i] > 5; })
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2fc9b8c8c7c5476)

Comment: This syntax is crazy.