# Is there a C++ way of implementing/equivalent of the which() function in R?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I'm re-writing an R program in c++. I'm wondering if there's a c++ equivalent or way of achieving the same result as the `which()` function in R. Here's what the `which()` function effectively accomplishes:

```
# A sequence 
x <- c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
# This should return a numerical index (1, 2) since only the first two elements are <= 20
which(x <= 20)
```

So `which()` essentially tests the expression and returns the TRUE indices of the logical object. I tried searching for an `Rcpp` sugar but can't seem to find one. There's `which_max()` and `which_min()`, which return the numerical indices for the max and min elements, respectively. I could always use the R function in Rcpp, but I'm interested in learning the c++ way *if possible*.

Comment: POC: you shoukd have `which(x <= 20)` NOT `which(x =<20)`

Comment: Good catch. Edited

Comment: Seems you will have to implement one yourself.

Comment: You might be looking at too fine a detail. Think about what you plan to do with the indices. The C++ way of achieving the same result might be a level higher than you are thinking; it might be to achieve the next thing you plan to do, rather than replicating this particular step along the way. *(For example, there are several standard algorithms with an `_if` form, which would essentially take `x <= 20` as an argument. These algorithms would operate only on the indices that `which` would have returned, skipping the part where you get to see the indices.)*

Comment: There usually isn't a 1-1 mapping between languages since they have very different design philosophies. You usually need to reshape your thinking too when going from one language to another (and that also means letting go of some favorite constructs from your previous languages)

Comment: also the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12990148/get-all-positions-of-elements-in-stl-vector-that-are-greater-than-a-value/12990554#12990554) does solve the problem at hand

Comment: Very insightful. Love the 1-1 mapping analogy. And I do need to think about what I want to do with the indices. It's also good to know that there's a way to solve the problem at hand.

Comment: have a look at `pryr::see_c_source(.Internal(which(x)))` - [This github](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/f9c955fc6699a1f0482e4281ba658215c0e0b949/src/main/summary.c#L1121-L1190).

Comment: Please try a search with `[rcpp[ which is:question` (and yes, with the square brackets and the colon, these are question operators for StackOverflow) as this has been asked, and answered _multiple_ times before.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a C++20 compatible compiler at hand this moment so I didn't test this.
But with C++20 and ranges you should be able to do something like this :
Note this won't return the indices, but a view on the actual values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>

// setup a predicate
auto which = [](const int& value ) { return value <= 20; };

int main()
{
    // or you can use std::vector
    std::array x{10,20,30,40,50};

    // create a filtered result
    auto result  = x | std::views::filter(which);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This, while true, is not a Rcpp answer.  See the context of the question.

Comment: But it is  an uncomplicated c++ answer. Not dependent on external libraries, which I think in this case is a valid solution.

Comment: I am mostly just suggesting to wrap it in something callable from Rcpp (as opposed to `main`) which is what the OP asked.  Details -- appreciate the answer.  The question is common and in fact a duplicate multiple times over anyway.

Comment: Oh now I get your point. But op didn't ask for that. He asked how to rewrite it in c++ not to make it callable from r

Comment: Well he did implicitly via the `rcpp` tag and the 'from R' context.  But I acknowledge that that is clear to me, but less so to someone pulled in via the `c++` tag.  All good.

Comment: Sure all good 